# integration by parts formula on unbounded domain

Tags: integration

Is integration by parts formula (for functions of several variables) valid on unbounded domains? Please give a proof or reference.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int\limits_a^{+\infty} f\,dg=\lim_{b\to\infty}\int\limits_a^b f\,dg=\lim_{b \to \infty}\left ( f(b)g(b)-f(a)g(a)-\int\limits_a^b gdf\right)$$

So the answer is:

If $f$ and $g$ are such functions that:

1. $\exists \text{finite}\lim\limits_{b\to\infty} f(b)g(b)$
2. $\int\limits_a^{+\infty}g(x)df(x)$ converges

,then the formula is valid.

And it's easy to make an analogue for unbounded below or totally unbounded domains.